# List with nested list as datasource in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm building an application which displays laptimes during a race.
I have a class that holds the participants with a nested list that holds their laptimes.

```
public class ParticipantClass
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public List<TimeSpan> LapTimes {get; set;}
}
```

Now I would like to display this list of participants in a DataGridView. As far as I know, it's not possible to display a list with nested lists in a DataGridView directly. I think I need to convert the list first to another "DisplayClass" which I can then bind to the DataGridView. The problem is, that I don't know how many Laptimes there will be. One participant might do 10 laps, but another might do 20. So ideally this "DisplayClass" can have dynamic Laptimes. Is there any way to accomplish this?

An other approach would be to set a fixed size for the displayclass to hold 100 LapTimes for example, but that would seem a bit of a waste of resources (eventhough the user wouldn't even notice it) but I'm just wondering if there not a better way of doing it.

[EDIT]
The desired output of the DataGridView would be something like this:

```
1 | John | Doe | 20.02 | 21.54 | 19.41 | 19.66 | 19.12
2 | Jane | Doe | 15.41 | 15.36 | 15.02 | 15.88 | 14.44 | 14.80 | 13.95 | 14.54
3 | ...
```

Comment: What do you actually want to display in DataGrid, can you show an example? I'm asking because I don't see a connection between list of participants and list of their lap times - in terms of DataGrid representation

Comment: A DGV is a flat table.  So whenever you you have a object with a list you must include all the other columns with each object of the list.  So you would have a table with 1234, John, Smith 12:15 then  1234, John, Smith 12:20 repeating the first three columns (or leaving blank except first row) of a group.

Comment: I've added a sample output in the original Questio @DarjanBogdan

Answer (score 0):

you could use method like this

```
    private DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<ParticipantClass> participants){
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        table.Columns.Add("ID");
        table.Columns.Add("FirstName");
        table.Columns.Add("LastName");
        var maxTimeLaps = 0;
        foreach (var p in participants) {

            // Create the row's data.
            List<Object> array = new List<Object> { p.ID, p.FirstName, p.LastName };
            array.AddRange(p.LapTimes.Cast<Object>());

            // Add additional columns for larger sets of TimeLaps.
            if (maxTimeLaps < p.LapTimes.Count) {
                for (int i = maxTimeLaps; i < p.LapTimes.Count; i++) {
                    table.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
                }
                maxTimeLaps = p.LapTimes.Count;
            }

            // Add new row to table.
            table.Rows.Add(array.ToArray());
        }

        return table;

    }
```

for generating a flat view of your data without changing the data-model.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to “flatten” the data as you describe. Specifically, in the posted example, you need to know how many columns are needed in the `DataTable.` This will require adding a new column to the table if you come across a `Participant` that has more Lap times than any of the previous `Participant`s. You can do this is in “one” loop through the list as shown in Kinimod’s answer.

The approach I use will loop through the list twice. Once to get the number of columns needed, then again to add the rows from the list. Since we will “know” that we will NOT have to add extras columns when adding the data, this will make adding the rows much easier and less complicated.

To start, I used a class similar to the one posted with some minor changes to the ID and added a simple constructor. It may look something like…

```
public class Participant {

  private static int count = 1;
  public int ID { get; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public List<TimeSpan> LapTimes { get; set; }

  public Participant(string firstName, string lastName) {
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
    ID = count++;
  }
}
```

Next, I created another class called `Participants.`  This class will hold the `List<Participant>` object. You could easily make a global `List<Participant>` and use it, however, I am confident this is a better approach considering you may want to check things like a duplicate `Participant` in the list before adding it to the list, or in this case, it will become a convenient place to put the two methods we need. 1) a method that returns an `int` number that indicates the count of the “largest” Lap list from all the `Paticipant`’s in the `List<Parcipitant>`; 2) a method to return a `DataTable` from the “flattened” list. This method will use the first method to get the column count needed. Again, it is in this class that you could add other “specific” methods to add, delete, lookup or sort the list. The bare bones for this example may look something like below.

```
public class Participants {

  public List<Participant> All_Participants { get; set; }

  public Participants() {
    All_Participants = new List<Participant>();
  }

  private int TotalColumns {
    get {
      int tot = 0;
      foreach (Participant participant in All_Participants) {
        if (participant.LapTimes.Count > tot)
          tot = participant.LapTimes.Count;
      }
      return tot;
    }
  }

  public DataTable GetParticipantDataTable() {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
    int totColumns = this.TotalColumns;
    for (int i = 1; i <= totColumns; i++) {
      dt.Columns.Add("Lap_" + i, typeof(TimeSpan));
    }
    foreach (Participant participant in All_Participants) {
      DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
      dr["ID"] = participant.ID;
      dr["FirstName"] = participant.FirstName;
      dr["LastName"] = participant.LastName;
      int curLapCol = 1;
      foreach (TimeSpan span in participant.LapTimes) {
        dr["Lap_" + curLapCol] = span;
        curLapCol++;
      }
      dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    return dt;
  }
}
```

That is pretty much all you need. Below is an example using the above classes. Note: When getting the sample data, a random number is used to define the max number of lap times generated for each participant which could be minimum of 1 lap to a maximum of 20 laps. Therefore, each time the code is run, you should expect different results.

```
Participants All_Participants;
Random rand = new Random();
DataTable GridTable;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  All_Participants = GetParticipantsList();
  GridTable = All_Participants.GetParticipantDataTable();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridTable;
}

private Participants GetParticipantsList() {
  Participants allPar = new Participants();
  Participant curPar = new Participant("John", "Doe");
  curPar.LapTimes = GetRandomLapTimes();
  allPar.All_Participants.Add(curPar);
  curPar = new Participant("Jane", "Doe");
  curPar.LapTimes = GetRandomLapTimes();
  allPar.All_Participants.Add(curPar);
  curPar = new Participant("Speedy", "Gonzalez");
  curPar.LapTimes = GetRandomLapTimes();
  allPar.All_Participants.Add(curPar);
  curPar = new Participant("Flash", "Gordon");
  curPar.LapTimes = GetRandomLapTimes();
  allPar.All_Participants.Add(curPar);
  curPar = new Participant("Usain", "Bolt");
  curPar.LapTimes = GetRandomLapTimes();
  allPar.All_Participants.Add(curPar);
  return allPar;
}

private List<TimeSpan> GetRandomLapTimes() {
  List<TimeSpan> times = new List<TimeSpan>();
  int numberOfLapTimes = rand.Next(1, 21);
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLapTimes; i++) {
    times.Add(new TimeSpan(0, rand.Next(31), rand.Next(60)));
  }
  return times;
}
```

The code above will display the lap times in the `DataGridView` in an hh:mm:ss format. If you only want to display the “mm:ss”, then you could wire up the grids `CellFormatting` event to format the lap time columns as you have shown. The code below should set the lap time in the “mm:ss” format.

It is unclear if you want the user to be able to “edit” the lap times. If you do allow the users to edit the lap times… It should be noted that even though the lap times are displayed as “mm:ss” if you change a lap time you MUST still enter the “hh” values since the column is of a `TimeSpan` type. Example, if you enter “12:14” into a lap time cell and press the enter key, the display will show “14:00.” You must enter all three parts of the time to have it display correctly… i.e. “00:12:14.”

In addition, if you allow the user to edit the lap time cells it would be prudent to wire up the grids `DataError` event to handle the situations where the user tries to enter 24 for hours, or 60 for minutes or 60 for seconds. Each of the values is invalid for a `TimeSpan` object and will throw a `DataError` exception. The grids `CellFormatting` event may look something like below.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
  if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0 && !dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) {
    string curColName = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
    if (curColName.Length >= 4) {
      if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Substring(0, 4).Equals("Lap_")) {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value.ToString())) {
          e.Value = ((TimeSpan)e.Value).ToString(@"mm\:ss");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.